# Many to Many SQL Query Join

Tags: mysql, sql

Am attempting to query the following. Basically clients can be in a number of categories. I have a list of check boxes of the categories and want to only display the clients of the selected categories. I have been trying to use an inner join but my SQL is still in its infancy and I am clearly getting it wrong . Any advice greatly appreciated . Thanks for reading.

my tables layout : http://www.uk-wired.co.uk/images/sample.jpg

[image]

Comment: What's your SQL statement so far?

Comment: My brain finally engaged and I nearly got there with : SELECT * FROM photosms.clients 
INNER JOIN photosms.clientscategories
ON photosms.clientscategories.idclient = photosms.clients.idclient
WHERE photosms.clientscategories.idcat = 12 or photosms.clientscategories.idcat = 16 ;                          values will be replaced with checkbox values. One problem though. If the client exists in more than one category they are retrieved multiple times how would I adjust query to only have the client once if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from clients join clientscategories on clients.idclient=clientscategories.idclient join categories on clientscategories.idcat=categories.idcat WHERE clientscategories.idcat IN (v1,v2,......)
```

I think you can try this, Please provide the values that you are selecting from check boxes to v1,v2...

Comment: Thanks this was the solution however if the client exists in multiple categories they are retrieved by the query multiple times. How could I adjust the query to only have the client retrieved once. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from clients join clientscategories on clientscategories.clientid=clients.clientid where clientscategories.idcat IN (value1,value2,......)
```

i hope this dummy query ll help you to achieve your goal.

Answer (score -1):

First, you should add another column like 'Status' in Client table. And in code level you should take a variable which hold a string like selected or unselected. Apply condition like

```
if(checkbox.checked)
status = "selected";
else
status = "Unselected";

then insert client.
```

after that you can apply query like...

```
select clientscategories.idclients, clientscategories.idcat, cleints.title etc..  from clientscategories join categories
on  clientscategories.idcat = categories.idcat
join clients
on clientscategories.idclient = clients.idclients
where clients.status = 'Selected'
```